# Is "syslog" often used to refer to both a protocol and an implementation?

Tags: syslog

Is "syslog" [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) a protocol?

Is "syslog" often used to refer to both a protocol and an implementation?  If it is sometimes used to refer to an implementation, how may I tell whether it refers to the protocol or an implementation? Does it by default refer to one particular implementation?  For example, what do the following articles refer to by "syslog"?

- https://www.networkmanagementsoftware.com/what-is-syslog/
- https://stackify.com/syslog-101/
- https://stackify.com/linux-logs/
- http://www.aboutlinux.info/2005/01/system-logging.html

Are "syslogd" in the following two  manpages the same or two different implementations of the protocol:

- https://linux.die.net/man/8/sysklogd
- https://manpages.debian.org/testing/inetutils-syslogd/syslogd.8.en.html

?

Are rsyslogd and syslog-ng  two other implementations of the protocol?

Answer (score 2):

In short - yes, all of the above.

The term "syslog" is overloaded, and can be used to refer to the protocol, the implementation, or even just the location of the logs that it generates, rather than having to ask "what distribuion?" before giving a specific path. What it's referring to at any given time must be determined by the context within which the term is used; as you've pointed out, both `rsyslogd` and `syslog-ng` are specific implementations of the protocol, but are often included in the definition of the term "syslog" when using it generically to mean "the default out-of-the-box system logging facility for the distribution you're working on".

Comment: And for added confusion, there’s the unfortunately-named [`syslog` system call on Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syslog.2.html) which gives access to the kernel message ring buffer.